# Java Script Errors in IE Vs FireFox?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I use the following script for get the values from HTML Table.If I use  **innerText** ,It will work on IE and Chrome Fine.But FireFox show the **Error: row.cells[0].innerText is undefined Source**.If I use **textContent** It will work Fine in Chrome and FireFox.But IE Shows the Following Error **cells.0.textContent' is null or not an object**.How to change this script Work on **IE,Chrome,FireFox** without Error? I use either c= row.cells[0].innerText.strip();**or** c=row.cells[0].textContent.strip();

```
        function a()
        {

            var table = getServerObject("b");
            var row,c;
            for (var i = 2; i < table.rows.length - 1; i++)
            {
                row = table.rows[i]; 
                if(row.cells.length==1)continue;
                c= row.cells[0].innerText.strip(); //It was work in chrome and IE (or)
                c=row.cells[0].textContent.strip();//It was work in chrome and FF
                if(c==0)
               {
                //Something
               }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Read [`This`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerText)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just test before using the property, which is available:

```
var contentEnabled = document.textContent === null;
```

Later on you have a if to decide, which property to use

```
if ( contentEnabled ) {
  c= row.cells[0].textContent.strip(); // It was work in chrome and FF
} else {
  c= row.cells[0].innerText.strip(); // It was work in chrome and IE
}
```

or shorter as suggested by @RobW

```
c = row.cells[0][contentEnabled ? 'textContent' : 'innerText'].strip();
```

For the slight differences between both properties note the following from the [MDN docu on `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent):

> **Differences from innerText**
>
> Internet Explorer introduced `element.innerText`. The intention is pretty much the same with a couple of differences:
>
> Note that while `textContent` gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and `<style>` elements, the mostly equivalent IE-specific property, `innerText`, does not.
>       `innerText` is also aware of style and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas `textContent` will.
>       As `innerText` is aware of CSS styling, it will trigger a reflow, whereas `textContent` will not.

Comment: That same page says that `document.textContent` is explicitly `null` if it's supported, otherwise it's `undefined`. I think you'd be better off checking `"textContent" in document`.

Comment: To reduce repetition, I would use `c = row.cells[0][contentEnabled ? 'textContent' : 'innerText'].strip();`. Also `... === null ? true : false` can be shortened to `... === null`.

Comment: @RobW Edited and included. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function a()
        {

            var table = getServerObject("b");
            var row,c;
            for (var i = 2; i < table.rows.length - 1; i++)
            {
                row = table.rows[i]; 
                if(row.cells.length==1)continue;
                   if(typeof (row.cells[0]) != "undefined"){
                c= row.cells[0].innerText.strip(); //It was work in chrome and IE (or)
                c=row.cells[0].textContent.strip();//It was work in chrome and FF
                if(c==0)
               {
                //Something
               }
                 }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want a cross-browser way (IE<9), use jQuery. Seriously, you will spend a lot less time with these quirks.

Based on its inspiration, you can do it like it does: use `nodeValue`, the only cross-browser way. However, `nodeValue` doesn't work on elements, but it does work on `textNodes` ([full list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeValue) on which elements it works).

```
function getText( el ) {
    var text = '';

    // Recursively get the text
    ( function recur( el ) {

        // If it's a textNode or a CDATA node
        if ( el.nodeType === 3 || el.nodeType === 4 ) {
            text += el.nodeValue;
        }

        // If it has childNodes, recursively get their nodeValue
        if ( el.hasChildNodes() ) {
            for ( var i = 0, l = el.childNodes; i < l; i++ ) {
                recur( el.childNodes[ i ] );
            }
        }
    } () );
    return text;
}
```

Usage:

```
getText( row.cells[0] );
```

If you don't care about the differences (`innerText` and `textContent` don't return the same output, not to mention which elements it gets, there are also textNodes differences) and just want a quick solution, use this:

```
function getText( el ) {
    if ( 'textContent' in el ) return el.textContent;
    else return el.innerText;
}
```